# Component not rendering any values on page from object passed in as prop

Tags: reactjs

The following example is pretty simple. When `new Book(id);` is called, the `Book` constructor will make an API call to my backend API, get the JSON data for the book, and set the properties on `Book` like `title`, `synopsis`, etc.

The `<BookDetailComponent />` is simply supposed to render details of the `Book` instance.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Book from "../../../modules/books";

export default function BookDetail(props) {
    let {id} = useParams();
    let book = new Book(id);
    return (
        <BookDetailComponent book={book} />
    )
}

export class BookDetailComponent extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.props.book.title}</h2>
                <div>
                    {this.props.book.synopsis}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I can see that the data has been received by `BookDetailComponent` in the React devtools tab. As you can see in the screenshot, `props.book` is an object with a title, synopsis, etc.

However, none of this information appears to render on the page.

[image]

EDIT:

As requested, here's the code for `Book`:

```
export default class Book {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id
    }

    load = (callback) => {
        Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/books/${this.id}`).then(response => {
            this.author_id = response.data.author_id
            this.title = response.data.title
            this.synopsis = response.data.synopsis
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your`Book` module and how exactly it updates value fetched from API call

Comment: I guess there is asynchronous code in your Book constructor. My assumption is that `book` variable is given as props before the information is set. Since objects are given by reference, react won't re-render because the reference didn't change.

Comment: alright, I've added the code for `Book`

Comment: It's async and you don't wait for the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your Book module makes an async call when load function is called. Now it does't trigger a re-render for the BookDetail component to reflect the updated values. Also you cannot directly call the async api in render as of today

I suggest you convert Book into a custom hook that fetches data and use it

```
const useBook = (id) => {
    const [book, setBook] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/books/${this.id}`).then(response => {
          setBook({
            author_id: response.data.author_id,
            title: response.data.title,
            synopsis: response.data.synopsis,
        });
    }, [id]);
    return book
}
export default useBook;
```

---

```
import useBook from "../../../modules/books";

export default function BookDetail(props) {
    let {id} = useParams();
    let book = useBook(id);
    return (
        <BookDetailComponent book={book} />
    )
}
```